# Developing a cordova App in iOS, Tags looping

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

Hi Guys I am a native iOS developer and I am working on hybrid app using web technologies. I am creating a dynamic div in jQuery getting rjson data from ajax call. So I am populating the list of questions on the page and each question has the question title, no. of views, no. of answers, no. votes and the tags. The problem I am having with my tag is, if there are two tags, it comes in a same span and when I try to loop the span, it is treating every alphabet as a separate tag and persisting the tags for example if first question has one tag, the second question will have first question tag and its own tag. Any help will appreciated.

```
 if(rjson != null ){
if(rjson.length)
{
   var htmlString = '';
   var tags  = "";
   for(i=0; i<rjson.length;i++){  
      var jsontitle=rjson[i].title.toLowerCase();
/*this is for search input*/
      if(jsontitle.search(valThis) != -1 )
/**/
         continue;
      htmlString = htmlString + '<div class="kmforum_body_area_row" style="overflow-x:hidden; position : relative; width:100%; float:left; "><div style="width:100%; height:auto; float:left;"></div>';

      htmlString = htmlString + '<div id="oppToggle'+ count +'" class="toggle" style=" width:99%; padding:10px; float:left; margin: 0; ">'+
               '<div style="width:87%; height:auto; float:left;" onclick=kmforumAnswerList($("#groupid'+i+'").val(),$("#questiontext'+i+'").val(),$("#questiontitle'+i+'").val(),$("#questiontags'+i+'").val(),$("#questionscore'+i+'").val());>'+

               '<div  style="float:left; padding-left:10px;'+ 'font-size:12px; width: 95%;">'+
               '<div  style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; text-shadow:none; height: auto; color:#336699;'+
               ' width:100%;">'+  rjson[i].title + '<input id="groupid'+i+'" type="hidden"  value="'+ rjson[i].id +'"></input>' + 
               '<input id="questiontext'+i+'" type="hidden"  value="'+ rjson[i].QuestionText +'"></input>' +
               '<input id="questiontitle'+i+'" type="hidden"  value="'+ rjson[i].title +'"></input>' +
               '<input id="questiontags'+i+'"  type="hidden"  value="'+ rjson[i].tagnames +'"></input>' +
               '<input id="questionscore'+i+'"  type="hidden"  value="'+ rjson[i].score +'"></input>' +

               '</div>'+
              '<div style="color:black;  white-space: nowrap; text-shadow:none; overflow: hidden;'+
              'text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%;">'+  rjson[i].score +' votes ' +rjson[i].view + ' views ' + rjson[i].ans_count + ' answers '+ '</div>'+
      '<div style="float:left; padding-left:3px;">' ;
/*this is for looping spans*/
              for(j=0; j < rjson[i].tagnames.length; j++){
         tags +='<span style="float:left; margin:0 auto; border-radius: 5px; background-color:#A9F5F2; white-space: nowrap; text-shadow:none; overflow: hidden;">'+  rjson[i].tagnames[j] + '</span>'  ;
      }

      htmlString +=tags+'</div>'+
              '<div style="width:35%; font-size:10px; float:right; color:#000000; white-space: nowrap; text-shadow:none; overflow: hidden;'+
              'text-overflow: ellipsis;">'+ rjson[i].author_name +'</div>'+
              '</div>'+

               '</div></div>'+
               '</div></div>';
      $('#iddivtitlelistcontent').html(htmlString);
            count = count + 1;

   }               

}
```

This is the code I am using .

Comment: Can you give a JSFiddle?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't have one and I am really not very sure about it is? Like I mentioned I am native iOS developer, not much familiar with JS and its frameworks. Thanks

Comment: JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ Here you can post your JS code and also html /css if needed,for  others to view your code in action and try to solve your problem.